# Magento: www.mysite.com/?SID="number" is appearing in one of the google urls

Tags: magento, url, search

I was searching on all my urls using site:www.mysite.com to check if they are all redirecting well, but I found one of the url in google search have www.mysite.com/?SID="long number".

How to remove this url from google

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to remove url parameters in google webmastertools.

> 1. On the Dashboard, under Crawl, click URL Parameters.
> 2. Next to the parameter you want, click Edit. (If the parameter isn’t listed, click Add parameter. Note that this tool is case sensitive, so be sure to type your parameter exactly as it appears in your URL.)
> 3. If the parameter doesn't affect the content displayed to the user, select No ... in the Does this parameter change... list, and then click Save. If the parameter does affect the display of content, click Yes: Changes, reorders, or narrows page content, and then select how you want Google to crawl URLs with this parameter. -- [URL parameters - Webmaster Tools Help](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1235687?hl=en)